# Laravel 5.2 Class does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on creating a social network. I am using codecourse's(https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpOIUW62tnJTtpWFABxWZ8g) tutorial as a guide.

This is the error message: **Class Chatty\Http\Controllers\HomeController does not exist**

### HomeController.php

```
<? php

namespace Chatty\Http\Controllers;

use Chatty\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }

}
```

### routes.php

```
<?php

Route::get('/', [
  'uses' => 'HomeController@index',
  'as' => 'home',
]);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the path to your HomeController.php? Do you have any kind of PSR-4 autoloading set up for the `Chatty` namespace?

Comment: Also, it looks like you have a syntax error in your HomeController. You can't have a space between `<?` and `php`. It should be `<?php` with no spaces.

Comment: Thank you. I did not notice the space between the `<?` and `php`.

Answer (score 0):

Did set up Chatty in `composer.json`

```
{
...
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/",
      "Chatty\\": "app/Chatty/"
    }
...
}
```

**edit**
Also

I don't believe in Laravel that you can move the Controllers outside of 'app/Http/Controllers` but I am not 100% certain.

**edit**
Also

This 
`use Chatty\Http\Controllers\Controller;`

needs to be

`use Http\Controllers\Controller;`

unless you are extending a class in `Chatty\Http\Controllers\Controller;`

Comment: It did not work. My `composer.json` file already had `"Chatty\\": "app/"`. I added the app part too but that also didn't help.

Comment: I did not move it out of the folder. I just changed the name of my app to 'Chatty'.

Comment: have you tried killing `Chatty` 
`namespace Http\Controllers;`
`use Http\Controllers\Controller;`

Comment: I also tried the same without changing the name of the application but that too had the same error.